# Can I upgrade an iPhone 5S directly to 8.3 from 7.1.3?

Tags: ios, upgrade, iphone

I am unable to upgrade iOS from 7.1.3 to 8.3 on my iPhone 5S. Can I upgrade directly to 8.3 or do I have to do it in stages i.e. from 7.2 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean 8.1.3 … & also 7.1.2, as there never was a 7.1.3 afaik

You can go straight to it - in fact, there's no other option. It's the only route.
Apple stops signing old releases shortly after a new one comes out, so an older version wouldn't work, even if you got hold of it.

Safest route to any update is…

- Sync to iTunes
- Backup to iTunes
- Download the update from iTunes, without updating.
- Update as a separate step [ensures the download is full & complete before starting]

Belt & braces - you have a full, recent backup of the current state should anything go wrong.

Comment: I tried that but it hangs up after several hours of download. Tried this three times after connecting to macbook pro but failed I do not know why. Direct download / update on iPhone 5s failed 5 times. Never knew that Apple could make such a painful process of updating.

Comment: 'hangs up after several hours of download' That would be your connection, nothing to do with Apple. I can get an ipsw file in about 30s. Try getting the file via http://ipswdownloader.com [files are from the same place but you can use a downloader]

Comment: tell a lie - it took 4 mins.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from iOS 7.1.3 to iOS 8.3 beta. you do not have to update to iOS 8.2 beta first. Be warned: this will wipe all of your data.